# how to create a python virtualenv environment without prompt prefix?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to have a "default" virtual environment, and for such I don't want to have a prompt prefix. The following option allows one to customize the prompt prefix for for a given environment:

```
--prompt=PROMPT       Provides an alternative prompt prefix for this environment
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use it to set an empty prefix. Is there a way for that?

I was using `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` to disable prompt prefix globally, but I changed my mind once I came to know the `--prompt` option. I want to choose the environment to have no prefix.

Comment: Why would you want to use `--prompt` to set an empty prefix, when `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` is specifically set up to do this?

Comment: @Xymostech it's not specifically done to do this. I think I explain the use case pretty clearly. For a given environment I never want the prefix when it's active, for all others, it should show up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set the `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` environment variable to `1` before sourcing `bin/activate`.

If you can't (or don't want to) do this, then you'll have to manually remove the relevant lines from `bin/activate`. You'll want to delete:

```
if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
    # ...
fi
```